# Redirect from web routes using can

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

By default on using `can` if not authorized, an exception is thrown. I want to redirect instead of showing this exception.

**web.php**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function(){
    Route::get('/users', [userController::class, 'index'])->can('view', 'user');
});
```

The exception is executed from `response.php`:

```
public function authorize()
{
    if ($this->denied()) {
        throw (new AuthorizationException($this->message(), $this->code()))
                    ->setResponse($this);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

I tried to redirect from there but it's not working:

```
public function authorize()
{
    if ($this->denied()) {
        return redirect('/');
    }

    return $this;
}
```

**UserPolicy.php:**

```
public function view(User $user)
{
    return $user->hasPermission('user-view');
}
```

is it possible to redirect instead of throwing this exception or I have to check from the controller and redirect from there?

Comment: Use a middleware.

Comment: @Innovin I'm using policies

Comment: @Innovin You mean `middleware(can:view,user)`?

Comment: You want to redirect a user if not authorized yeah? How do you determine this? is there some sort of id that checks a users authorization level?

Comment: update your question with the code of the ```$this->denied()``` method, then I will answer your question.

Comment: @Innovin `auth` middleware + policy are used to determine that the user is logged in and has  permission to access this route

Comment: If you just need to redirect the user if not logged in. Just add the middleware: auth to your route as such ```Route::get('/users', [userController::class, 'index'])->middleware('auth');```

Comment: @Innovin `Auth` middleware already used. I want to redirect if the user doesn't have the permission

Comment: I updated the question with `Auth` and policy

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? I'm kinda lost.

Comment: If this fails `can('view', 'user')`, I want to redirect not to show exception

Comment: have your exception handler deal with the exception and return a redirect

Comment: @lagbox Do you know where to find it?